# Atom custom language package not picking up file extensions or highlighting correctly

Tags: package, grammar, squarespace, atom-editor

I'm trying to build a simple atom package that displays some filetypes associated with squarespace development in the correct highlighted way. Iv'e tried reading the docs and looking at related packages and mirroring mine off of theirs but it seems no matter what I do atom wont pickup that these file types have an associated language package installed, and when I manually apply my language it doesn't even highlight them correctly.

The associations I'm trying to build are

- .block -> html
- .region -> html
- .list -> html
- .item -> html
- .conf -> json
- .preset -> json

my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "language-squarespace",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "description": "Syntax Highlighting for SquareSpace files",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/blaketarter/language-squarespace"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "atom": "*",
    "node": "*"
  }
}
```

and an example of one of my grammar files is

```
'filetypes': [
  'block'
]

'name': 'block (squarespace)'

'patterns': [
  {
    'include': 'source.html'
  }
]

'scopeName': 'source.block'
```

I feel like im missing something important because I based mine off of https://github.com/rgbkrk/language-ipynb and things seem to match.